# Telegram WebApp (MiniApp) size changed on desktop

Tags: web-applications, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

After September 22, 2023 Telegram Bot API update all WebApp (new Mini App) windows shrank twice. However, there is no information about that on official change log.

I attach photos of the window size before and after September update.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUcUC.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb9X3.jpg)

Is there a way to return old window size?

I tried using `expand()` method, but it didn't help. I also didn't manage to find any information about that change.